# Image processing using chaquopy on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, chaquopy

I followed all the instructions to import chaquopy on Android Studio and my hello word program worked but when I am trying to run HOG program in which I am importing skimage, it is giving me error as no module named skimage. I have added the required libraries inside the pip block of module level build.gradle file but still it is giving me the error. I am using chauopy version 6.3.0 and Android gradle version 3.5.0.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage import data, color, exposure
from PIL import Image
#%%
img = io.imread(r"Insert\Image\Path\Here.jpg")
#im= Image.open(r"Insert\Image\Path\Here.jpg")
image = color.rgb2gray(img)
```

PIP block in build.gradle file

```
python{

   pip{

             install "scikit-image"
             install "numpy"
             install "matplotlib"
             install "scikit-learn"

        }
 }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the pip block from your build.gradle.file.

Comment: Thank you for responding @mhsmith. I have edited the question.

Comment: I took the [Chaquopy console template](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy-console/), pasted this code into the `main` function, and pasted this `pip` block into the build.gradle file. As expected, the imports work fine, and it gets as far as a `FileNotFoundError` on the `imread` call. So I'm not sure what you could be doing differently. Are you sure you rebuilt and reinstalled the app after updating the `pip` block?

Comment: Yes i rebuild the project many times but still it is giving me error.

Comment: Rebuilt AND reinstalled on the device?

Comment: If you still can't work it out, it might be helpful to edit the question to add the full stack trace.

Comment: Are you talking about reinstalling chauopy in Android studio or reinstalling my app? As import line is giving me the error, I am not able to run it on my device.

Comment: I mean reinstalling the app on the device after you build it. That is, you should use the green play button ("Run") rather than the green hammer button ("Make project"). Sorry if you already know this, but sometimes people make that mistake.